# Is there a way to have an Express app packaged with pkg reference local files not included in the pkg assets?

Tags: node.js, express

I made a little `create-react-app` app as a utility for a friend. I want to serve it with `express`, and package it all up with `pkg` so that he doesn't have to install Node or anything and can just double-click an executable and open a browser to use it.

So far I have it working except for the images.  The problem is that there are over 2.7 GB of images, so I don't want to package all that up by specifying them as `assets` for `pkg`.

How can I get the packaged app to see the local filesystem so the images can stay out of the executable package?

Comment: What about deploying to a free host like heroku or nextjs and just give friend the url?

Comment: Specify the path to the images via a environment variable and serve them via express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is... use `nexe` instead.

Don't know what's going on under the hood between them, but I was able to package what I wanted (the `node` server) as an executable, and exclude all the images, and have the site run locally as expected when the `express` server was started up by running the executable.